Is it possible to identify who triggered a GCB build?
Let's say I have a Cloud Build workflow, and I trigger it by running gcloud builds triggers run my-workflow.
Is it possible for the Cloud Build workflow to identify "who" triggered it? That is, can the workflow somehow figure out that it was called by wasabi@foo.com or 1234567890-service-account@google.com? (Having the user pass their email as a --substitution doesn't count)
To be clear, this isn't about identifying the service account which is running the build; that's available directly via $SERVICE_ACCOUNT[_EMAIL]. This is about identifying who ran gcloud builds triggers run.
After some digging, I've seen mentions to IAP as a possible means of doing this, but always in the context of Cloud Functions or actual apps and services. I'm therefore unsure if this is possible with GCB. If it is true, I'm also unclear on how to use it:

Does it change anything for the caller? Do they need to perform some action or run some additional command, or can they simply keep running gcloud builds triggers run, with IAP working invisibly in the background?
How can the workflow figure out that identity?


It would be possible by reading the audit logs in the first step of the Cloud Build pipeline, but why do you need to have this invoker email in the pipeline? Is it for notification purposes?

@guillaumeblaquiere this would be a centralized pipeline triggered by multiple teams, but the pipeline will only be granted access to specific credentials depending on who triggered it.

@guillaume-blaquiere is correct, the data is captured by Audit Logs.
I think (!) you don't need to enable Data Access audit logs but, if the logs don't include examples of the following, update the Data Access audit logs for "Cloud Build API" to include "Admin Read":
https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/audit?referrer=search&project=${PROJECT}
You can filter the audit logs for Cloud Build methods and the auth user:
PROJECT="..."

FILTER='
log_id("cloudaudit.googleapis.com/activity") 
protoPayload.serviceName=~"cloudbuild.googleapis.com"
'

FORMAT='
value(
  timestamp,
  protoPayload.methodName,
  protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail
)'

gcloud logging read "${FILTER}" \
--format="${FORMAT}" \
--project=${PROJECT}


I'd considered using the audit logs, but I couldn't figure out how "fresh" the relevant logs would be. Might a workflow be triggered before the relevant logs are available? This wouldn't be a deal-breaker; I can set up a retry loop until the logs are available, as long as it's a matter of seconds or even one or two minutes. However, I also couldn't figure out if it'd be possible for a workflow to identify itself in the logs; do the logs also contain the workflow ID or something like that, which can be used if there are concurrent runs of the workflow happening?

The audit log entry results from the Cloud Service method (e.g. Cloud Build deploy) being called so the log always follows the event. I'm unsure whether Google provides any guarantees on log entry availability. In my experience, log entries are available very quickly (~seconds) after the event.

I've deleted the Project that I created to test your question but I'm confident that the log entry identifies the workflow.

Undeleted the Project. Yes, the log entry contains e.g. {"resource":{"labels":{"build_id: REDACTED","build_trigger_id": "","project_id": "REDACTED","type": "build"}}}
